# Feature Selection using Fuzzy Logic

Tags: feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, fuzzy

I would like to know, Is it possible to do dimensionality reduction/ feature selection using Fuzzy logic ? If so, how does it work ?.

Advance thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes it is possible.

As for the second question, I'm definitely no expert on the subject. 
As far as I understand, the idea is that you first project the original features to a fuzzy space. Afterwards you can apply standard feature selection techniques.

I did find an academic paper that explains it much better than I can, hope it helps. https://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/f373/a216bdbf464b844df2c2d5654fd1d3f24325.pdf

-Edit-

The paper I added originally, seems to be a dead link now: 
For those looking for it, I can recommend the following papers:
http://sites.labic.icmc.usp.br/pub/mcmonard/CintraIHMSC09.pdf
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1e42/f50bacfb824e6684d7327cbace70178dfe81.pdf